# Lista dentro de lista JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, algoritmo

Olá, bom dia!

Eu estou fazendo um algoritmo em JS em que eu pego todos os paragrafo de um texto e coloco em um array, apos eu pego cada palavra desse mesmo paragrafo e coloco dentro de outro array, até aqui tudo ocorre bem.

Ao tentar percorrer todas as palavras dentro desse array de palavras que fica dentro do array de parágrafo, ele só vai até certo ponto(não pega todas as palavras do paragrafo).

Eu tentei fazer alguns debugs no DevTools, mas ele mostra que o array de palavras tem por exemplo 44 palavras, porém ele tende a pegar 33(Normalmente é um valor sempre menor ao total).

Queria a ajuda de vocês pra saber o que estou fazendo errado.

Código a abaixo:

```js
var conteudo = $("#editor").val(); // Pega os valor do textarea CKEDITOR
var arrayExterno = conteudo.split(/<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p.*?>/g);  // Coloca cada paragrafo dentro de um array

// Pega cada palavra dentro do paragrafo e coloca em um array interno ao array anterior
var arrayInterno = [];
for(i=0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++){
arrayInterno.push(arrayExterno[i].split(" "));
}

// Quantidade de vezes que a palavra chave foi encontrada
contPalavrasChaves = 0;
for(i=0; i<arrayExterno.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<arrayInterno.length; j++){
  if(arrayInterno[i].length > 1){
     console.log(arrayInterno[i][j]); // Resultado mostra até o tam 33 ao inves de todo o conteudo de cada paragrafo
         }        
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<textarea name="content" id="editor">
           Você sabia que existem diferentes tipos de vendas? Cada uma delas é indicada para um modelo de negócio e, se bem aplicada, pode facilitar a manutenção dos lucros. Inclusive em situações em que a equipe de vendas da empresa não possui muita experiência na área.

A ideia em adotar um dos tipos de vendas significa gerar identificação e uniformizar práticas. Seria como se todos os funcionários de sua empresa falassem o mesmo idioma. Por isso é tão importante escolher o tipo de venda ideal para sua empresa.

Afinal, quando um negócio possui uma estratégia bem definida, pode treinar seus funcionários com base nela, “moldando-os” de acordo com a sua política e objetivos. Afinal, como observou Dale Carnegie: "Quanto mais suor derramado em treinamento, menos sangue será derramado em batalha".

Pensando nisso, a seguir listamos os 5 principais tipos de venda, para que você avalie suas estratégias de negócio e possa otimizar os lucros da sua empresa. Confira!

1. Venda direta

Sendo o tipo mais conhecido e aplicado no mundo, a venda direta é aquela que mais deve se ajustar à missão de sua empresa. Se ainda não tem uma claramente definida, pense no que você faz e como isso impacta na vida das pessoas. Ou seja, seu grande objetivo é levar pessoas, objetos, bens ou valores de um ponto a outro. Portanto, se o tipo de venda que sua empresa faz é direta, cada abordagem de venda deve priorizar sua missão.

Destacar as qualidades de um produto ou serviço é parte do processo, mas o vendedor não pode perder de vista a finalidade daquilo que está sendo vendido. A venda direta pode ser feita de forma ativa, quando a equipe vai em busca de clientes por telefone, e-mail ou no tradicional porta a porta. Também pode ser passiva, na qual as pessoas são recebidas numa loja física, por exemplo. Em ambas abordagens, a argumentação precisa ser focada em atender às necessidades das pessoas e alinhar a missão da empresa às suas expectativas.

2. Vendas consignadas

A venda consignada existe justamente para diminuir a exposição ao riscopara microempresas e empresários individuais. Ao adquirir mercadorias para venda em consignação, o vendedor paga ao fornecedor apenas pelo que foi vendido, devolvendo o que não for negociado. É um dos tipos de vendas mais adotados por varejistas e distribuidores. Funciona da seguinte maneira: o fornecedor firma uma parceria com um estabelecimento comercial que assume as vendas das mercadorias e fica isento da responsabilidade de pagar pelo que não for vendido.

Empresas com uma estrutura de estoque e comercialização muito enxuta podem se beneficiar de pontos de venda consolidados de outras companhias. Como o fornecedor, nesse caso, assume o risco de não vender as mercadorias e arcar com as despesas com eventuais devoluções, o vendedor consignado conta com uma oportunidade segura de faturar sobre o produto.

3. Venda cruzada

Também conhecida pelo termo em inglês cross-selling, a venda cruzada é indicada para empresas que trabalham com mais de um tipo de produto ou serviço. Lojas de vestuário, por exemplo, podem se beneficiar da venda cruzada. Afinal, a venda de uma camiseta pode ser uma oportunidade de oferecer um par de óculos escuros.

Além disso, existe uma extensão desse tipo de venda chamada up-selling, que é quando o vendedor encoraja o cliente a gastar um pouco mais para ter um produto melhor que o que ele pretende levar. Essa prática é comum em concessionárias de automóveis quando o cliente é persuadido a comprar os itens de série do carro. Esse é um tipo de venda comum na indústria automotiva, mas não só nela.

4. Vendas casadas

Bem, esse tipo de venda é proibido em nosso país. A venda casada acontece quando um fornecedor condiciona a venda de um produto à aquisição de outro, obrigando o consumidor a uma compra forçada. Isto quer dizer que, ou você leva os dois (ou mais) produtos ou não leva nenhum! O que é totalmente ilegal e proibido pelo Código de Defesa do Consumidor. Na venda casada, para levar aquilo que você quer realmente comprar é necessário adquirir ou contratar uma outra coisa, já que tais mercadorias e serviços não são vendidos separadamente e por preços justos.

5. Vendas corporativas

A venda corporativa merece uma atenção especial. É um tipo de venda que se diferencia bastante de todos os outros modelos que citamos, a começar pelos personagens envolvidos na negociação. Quando falamos em vendas corporativas estamos tratando exclusivamente de vendas B2B. Nesse caso, portanto, a venda deve ser predominantemente pautada em argumentos racionais, embora as emoções possam ser trabalhadas em algumas etapas do processo. O vendedor precisa estar ciente de que nenhuma companhia contratará seu serviço ou comprará seu produto antes de passar um pente fino no seu negócio e em suas propostas.

Quando falamos em vendas corporativas em geral, estamos lidando com a prestação de serviços importantes, contratos de longa duração, transações significativas e outras negociações que exigem um processo de vendas muito mais complexo. Esse trabalho depende de uma equipe de vendas integrada a um time de Marketing. A ideia é criar um relacionamento de longo prazo com o público e conduzi-lo até o fechamento do negócio.

Antes de decidir qual tipo de venda aplicar no seu negócio, é muito importante que você tenha a missão dele bem definida. Pode parecer piada, mas no final das contas a sua missão é atingir seus objetivos empresariais. Isso é o que diferencia o sucesso do fracasso! Essa é a premissa básica que muitas empresas esquecem e por isso se perdem no processo.

E além de escolher o tipo de venda certo para seu negócio, ter um time de vendedores bem treinados capazes de combinar um discurso convincente e uma atitude carismática são técnicas muito eficazes para convencer os clientes da grandeza e necessidade do seu serviço ou produto.

Então, gostou desse post? Qual o tipo de vendas que você pratica na sua empresa? Ficou com alguma dúvida sobre as modalidades? Comente! E para qualquer dúvida ou sugestão, não hesite em falar conosco!
</textarea>
```

Desde já agradeço o tempo de vocês.

Comment: Se entrar no ` for(j=0; j<arrayInterno.length; j++){` já não é `arrayInterno[i].length > 1` ?

Comment: Opaaa meu amigo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Então... não exatamente, tinha alguns parágrafos que tem apenas uma string, então eu diminui a procura, retirando esses parágrafos com apenas poucas string.

Porém, mesmo assim o uso desse if é indiferente para o resultado, o problema persiste com ou sem essa linha.

Answer (score 0):

Gente, agradeço a todos vocês pela seu tempo, mas consegui resolver quebrando um pouco mais a cabeça.

A solução foi a seguinte:

```
var palavraChave = $("#palavra-chave").val();   // Alterar para o ID do campo
var conteudo = editor.getData();                            // Pega os valor do textarea CKEDITOR
var arrayExterno = conteudo.split(/<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p.*?>/g);  // Coloca cada paragrafo dentro de um array

// Pega cada palavra dentro do paragrafo e coloca em um array interno ao array anterior
var arrayInterno = [];
for(i=0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++){
arrayInterno.push(arrayExterno[i].split(" "));
}

// Quantidade de vezes que a palavra chave foi encontrada
contPalavrasChaves = 0;
for(i=0; i<arrayExterno.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<arrayInterno[i].length; j++){ // SOLUÇÃO -> Add o index [i] ao arrayInterno e assim me retornou o valor esperado
        if(arrayInterno[i] == palavraChave){
            console.log(arrayInterno[i][j]);               
        }  
    }
}
```

SOLUÇÃO(Linha de comentario add ao código) -> Add o index [i] ao arrayInterno e assim me retornou o valor esperado

Answer (score -2):

var palavraChave = $("#palavra-chave").val(); // Alterar para o ID do campo
var conteudo = editor.getData(); // Pega os valor do textarea CKEDITOR
var arrayExterno = conteudo.split(/<p.*?>(.*?)</p.*?>/g); // Coloca cada paragrafo dentro de um array

// Pega cada palavra dentro do paragrafo e coloca em um array interno ao array anterior
var arrayInterno = [];
for (i = 0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++) {
arrayInterno.push(arrayExterno[i].split(" "));
}

// Quantidade de vezes que a palavra chave foi encontrada
for (i = 0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < arrayInterno[i].length; j++) {
if (arrayInterno[i][j] == palavraChave) {
console.log(arrayInterno[i][j]);
}
}
}

/*Note que removi a variável contPalavrasChaves, pois ela não estava sendo usada no código. Se ela for necessária em algum momento, basta adicioná-la novamente e atualizá-la dentro do loop interno.*/

```js
var palavraChave = $("#palavra-chave").val(); // Alterar para o ID do campo
var conteudo = editor.getData(); // Pega os valor do textarea CKEDITOR
var arrayExterno = conteudo.split(/<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p.*?>/g); // Coloca cada paragrafo dentro de um array

// Pega cada palavra dentro do paragrafo e coloca em um array interno ao array anterior
var arrayInterno = [];
for (i = 0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++) {
  arrayInterno.push(arrayExterno[i].split(" "));
}

// Quantidade de vezes que a palavra chave foi encontrada
for (i = 0; i < arrayExterno.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < arrayInterno[i].length; j++) {
    if (arrayInterno[i][j] == palavraChave) {
      console.log(arrayInterno[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Note que removi a variável contPalavrasChaves, pois ela não estava sendo usada no código. Se ela for necessária em algum momento, basta adicioná-la novamente e atualizá-la dentro do loop interno.</h1>
```